# ¿Cómo asignar una imagen desde la carpeta mdpi a un ImageView en Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, imagen, xamarin

¿Cómo puedo asignar una imagen a un ImageView en Xamarin?

Para hacer esto antes lo que hacía era agregar las imágenes a "drawable" y desde modo diseño seleccionaba en el campo "src" la imagen, quedando algo asi:

> src | @drawable/splashlogo

y si lo quería hacer desde código en tiempo de ejecución solo ponía:

```
var drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable(Resources.GetIdentifier("splashlogo", "drawable", PackageName));
Icono.Background = (drawableImage);
```

El problema con este método es que empecé a tener problemas de consumo de memoria porque la resolución de las imágenes era mucha, y ahora que estoy usando las carpetas destinadas para cada densidad de pantalla (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi...) no se como asignar las imagenes ni en tiempo de ejecución ni en el diseño del layout.

Alguien me podria indicar como se hace por favor?

Comment: ¿Es Xamarin Android o es Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Es Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A como mencione en la pregunta yo lo podía realizar de esta manera cuando los archivos estaban en drawable:

```
var drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable(Resources.GetIdentifier("splashlogo", "drawable", PackageName));
Icono.Background = (drawableImage);
```

Pero no resultaba una vez que las imágenes estaban en las carpetas segun su densidad (mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-hdpi...)

[image: Imagen de carpetas mipmap drawable]

Así que al poner más atención y notar la palabra clave antes de cada carpeta (mipmap) la intente usar como "descripción" y me resulto, asi que la respuesta es esta para quien tenga el mismo problema:

```
ProfileIcon.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.splashlogo);
```

o

```
var drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable(Resources.GetIdentifier("splashlogo", "mipmap", PackageName));
ProfileIcon.SetImageDrawable(drawableImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesante pregunta, describes que tenías problemas de alojamiento de memoria al cargar la imagen desde el directorio `/drawable`

```
var drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable(Resources.GetIdentifier("splashlogo", "drawable", PackageName));
Icono.Background = (drawableImage);
```

Si en realidad estas definiendo ahora directorios `/drawable` para diferentes densidades, ahora debes agregar imágenes para esas densidades en esos directorios,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Únicamente debes indicar cargar la imagen desde "Drawable" y **el sistema operativo se encargará automáticamente de obtener la imagen adecuada para tu dispositivo**:

```
Drawable drawableImage = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.splashlogo);
Icono.Background = (drawableImage);
```

Comment: Para crear las imágenes según su densidad correspondiente estoy usando una herramienta que lo hace de manera automática, solo tengo que subir mi imagen y click en descargar y me descarga un archivo rar con todas las carpetas mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, etc. (Android Asset Studio - Launcher Icon Generator) 

El problema es que al cargar esas imágenes la resolución es demasiado mala y se ve espantoso, aun la xxhdpi. 
Hay alguna idea para solucionar esto?

Comment: @KennyAli de hecho lo ideal es usar el "Asset Studio" el problema que mencionas se debe  a que debes usar una imagen de buena resolución para generar los iconos o imágenes para distintas densidades, o usar un gráfico vectorial .svg, con esto obtendrías imágenes con buena resolución.